# Algebra problem...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boy was employed on the understanding that he was to receive p paise for every day he worked and q paise for everyday when there was no work for him. After d days his total earnings amounted to Rs P.How many days he had worked?Please make me understand this question

Comment: If he earns p paise a day when he works. Then he had worked for Rs days.

Comment: I don't understand  why is it Rs P

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have $p(w)+q(d-w)=P$ where $w$ is the number of days he worked and so $(d-w)$ is the number he did not. Now solve for $w$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d_{work}$ and $d_{free}$ be the number of days he worked and did not work, respectively. They must satisfy the following two equations.

\begin{align*}
d_{work}+d_{free}&=d\\
p\cdot d_{work}+q\cdot d_{free}&= P
\end{align*}

[This question is an exercise in solving a system of two equations in two unknowns $d_{work}$ and $d_{free}$.]

Comment: I believe Rs is the currency and P is the figure

Comment: @DavidPeterson Thanks, I wasn't familiar with that. After googling, it seems that maybe the right-hand side should be $100P$ instead of just $P$, as there are $100$ paise in a rupee.

Comment: Ah and I thought it was a mistranslation.